# ThreeJS: Exporting a scene to 3DS

Tags: three.js

Is it possible to export a three.js scene to a 3DS file?

I found exporters from Collada, DRACO, GLTF, MMD, OBJ, PLY and STL but not for 3DS.
Importing a 3DS file so far is not the problem but I after I changed something on the model I need to export the scene again.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to export a three.js scene to a 3DS file?

No, there is no exporter for this 3D format. And I guess it's unlikely that one will be developed because of the drawbacks of 3DS. It's an undocumented and proprietary 3D standard and way better alternatives exists.

The recommended 3D format of `three.js` is glTF. Use it whenever possible.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer.